# Display GeoTIFF layer from GeoServer in OpenLayers?

Tags: raster, geoserver, openlayers, geotiff-tiff

I have a number of GeoTIFF files to be published in GeoServer and consume in OpenLayers.

I have published vector data and I was able to consume them in OpenLayers. However, I am not able to show a sample GeoTIFF layer on OpenLayers (I created by placing the tiff file in GeoServer directory and published from there).

I used TileWMS source with Tile layer and ImageWMS source with Image layer, either way nothing gets rendered in OpenLayers. How can I display the GeoTIFF layer in OpenLayers?

code :

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/localhost/wms'

var multipleSrc = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    projection: 'EPSG:32643',
    url: url,
    params: {
        //'FORMAT': 'image/png',
        'LAYERS': 'localhost:Tiff',//getCommaSeperatedLayersFromHT(),
        //'TRANSPARENT': 'TRUE',
        //'CQL_FILTER': 'INCLUDE'//getCommaSeperatedLayersFromCQL() //"INCLUDE;INCLUDE;INCLUDE;INCLUDE;INCLUDE;INCLUDE;INCLUDE;tehsil='Jatara'" // Working
    },
    serverType: 'geoserver',
    //transition: 0,
    //transparent: true,
    //opacity: 0.5,
});

 var layers = [
    EsriLayer,
    //OSMLayer,
    multipleLayer,
    vector
  ];

  var view = new ol.View({
      center: washingtonWebMercator,
      zoom: 5,
      maxZoom: 19.9
  })
  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: layers,
    target: 'map',
    view: view
  });
```

Comment: TIF isn't supported by most browsers (internet explorer is an exception) so unless you want to be restricted to IE you would need to serve as a browser friendly format such as PNG

Comment: Thanks for the response ! We need to draw features on the TIFF, If PNG is supported then do I need to do any extra step to publish this as PNG ? Please suggest on how can I consume this in openlayers.  Also, In chrome I am able to see the published layer through openlayers preview.

Comment: A single geoTiff file size is around 80 MB

Comment: You might want to investigate integrating with these third party libraries https://geotiffjs.github.io/  https://eox.at/2018/01/visualizing-geotiff-tiles-with-openlayers/

Comment: @Mike, when you publish GeoTIFF with GeoServer through WMS it is usually not a tiff for the client anymore but some other image format like png or jpeg that the WMS server supports and WMS client requests. In this example OpenLayers request image data (natively a GeoTIFF) as jpeg https://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/nurc/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=nurc:Img_Sample&styles=&bbox=-130.85168,20.7052,-62.0054,54.1141&width=768&height=372&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers.

Comment: @user30184 Yes, I though I implied that in my first comment.  You can draw on OpenLayers regardless of the raster baselayer so I don't understand why they "need to draw features on the TIFF" when OpenLayers runs on browsers which you can't render TIFF.

Comment: We need to draw features like Line/Polygon etc on the provided Tiff files. I believe these features can be drawn using the PNG as well. But I am not able to render the base layer which I published from Tiff in openlayers. May be I am missing a basic point as I have recently started web Based GIS apps.

Comment: I have edited my question with my code. Please suggest.

Comment: You cannot draw features directly on any raster layer, you must overlay it with a vector layer and draw on that.

Answer (score 3):

I would go into the Layer Preview tab of the GeoServer admin console and select OpenLayers 3 (OL3) in the All Formats column.  Then you can use the browser's devtools to see the network request and the parameters used to successfully display the image.

You can also do a View Page Source in your browser to take a look at the exact OL3 code used to display the image successfully by GeoServer in OL3.

[image: Debugging layer issues]

[image: View Page Source results from the browser]